# Sql Server analysis Services 2008 Dynamic dimension security using MDX expression

Tags: security, sql-server-2008, ssas, mdx, dimensions

**Some dimension tables in my warehouse:**

```
DML
Site
    Id      bigint
    Name    nvarchar(256)
    Primary key (Id)

DATA
SiteId    Name
2         Site 2
3         Site A

DML
UserSite
    Username    nvarchar(256)
    SiteId      bigint
    Primary key (Username, SiteId)
    Foreign key (SiteId) referrences Site(Id)

DATA
Username    SiteId
EMSUser1    2
EMSUser1    3
EMSUser2    3
```

**My SSAS Project:**
I have used these two dimension tables in one dimension in a BIDS project, created using the dimension wizard.
The usernames relate to two local windows user accounts on the SSAS Server, they are members of a local windows 
group ReportBrowsers. I have created a Role for that group in BIDS and added an MDX Expression to the dimension Data tab 
for this dimension in the AllowedSet box for the Username attribute:

```
STRTOMEMBER("[UserSiteSite].[Username].["+Trim(Mid( UserName, InStr(1, UserName, "\")+ 1,128))+"]")
```

This dimension is used in a cube that's all processed and deployed. I then have an SSRS Report based on that cube.

**My intention:**
What I'm trying to do is take the logged in user currently browsing SSRS and remove the "<domain>\" part of the string returned 
effectively filtering the results to just the sites that username has a record for.

So for EMSUser1 I should see records for both sites, but it appears to be allowing the first one only ("Site 2" with Id 2) 
There's no sign of "Site A" even though records exist for that site in the fact table.

I've been trawling through Analysis Services 2008 unleashed and the step by step book and all over blogs etc. 
I just can't quite grok the internal workings to achieve my goal.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: It can be very hard to get your head around the idea of this 'hidden' filter. I have done a similar thing before, but I had to be very careful with something called "Visual Totals" in SQL Analysis Services 2000. I don't know what the consequences are in BIDS I am afraid. Sorry thats not very helpful. Believe me you must test very very carefully, with more test scenarios than you think necessary!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well it's been some time now. I don't have the complete answer even now but I did get some help else where that has lead me to a solution. The details can be found [here](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/sqlanalysisservices/thread/dddb30cf-bba8-4403-a0b7-a41210ba24c0).

There are a lot of ways to solve this kind of scenario. I feel there may still be a better one for me, but I have something that at least works. Basically create a seperate class library with a static class and function that makes it's own connection to the database and selects out the allowed set. If you reference the Microsoft.AnalysisServices
and Microsoft.AnalysisServices.AdomdServer namespaces you can return a 'Set' object. You can then call this function in the Role objects Dimension data advance tab:

```
MyAssembly.MyMethod(UserName)
```